# How to dynamically populate html content using reactjs?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to populate navigation bar items i.e navigation list using JSON data. I am trying to map through the data and display dropdown navigation items.

Example code of dropdown navigation:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Now I am trying to create a function `shownavlist()` which dynamically  populates the data inside navigation bar.

My code:

```
function shownavlist(allnavitems){

      const items = allnavitems.map( h => {
        return(
            h.links.map( display => {
              return(

                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle navbar-link" data-toggle="dropdown">{h.heading}<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu {{getTheme slug}}" role="menu">
                  <li><a class="navbar-link notAllowed" href="">{display.heading}</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>

              )
            })  
         )
      })

  }

<div class="container-fluid ">
              <div class="row">
              <div class="container">
                 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                      <li class="dropdown">

                        {shownavlist(allnavitems)}

                      </li>
                 </ul>
              </div>
              </div>
          </div>
```

I am getting error that map of undefined. How can I dynamically populate navigation bar content ?

JSON data: (console log) below in screenshot is `console.log(allnavitems)` data.

Comment: it should be `h.links.map`, `h` will be an object. i will suggest to use a meaningful name.

Comment: You are calling `map` again on every item inside the first `map`. But those are objects. Either get rid of the second `map` as you already have your objects, or maybe you intended to foreach the childs like `h.links.map(..)`?

Comment: @TobiasK I have edited code but I am getting error: cannot read map of undefined

Comment: @MayankShukla  I have edited code but I am getting error: cannot read map of undefined

Comment: Basically I want to display dropdown navigation items using shownavlist(allnavitems) { } function

Comment: links[ ] array can be zero also i.e empty [ ] so I added if(h.links.length !== 0) but it still doesn't work

Comment: @stonerock you are not passing any value to function: `{shownavlist()}`, because of that `allnavitems` will be undefined.

Comment: @MayankShukla This should be an answer. This is the problem why allnavitems is undefined.

Comment: Sorry guys I have edited the code. But it is still not working

Comment: @MayankShukla Can you please add an answer because the function does not displays anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initial issue was, you were not passing any value to `{shownavlist()}` because of that `allnavitems` was undefined inside `shownavlist` function.

Another issue is, you are not returning anything from `shownavlist` function, by default function will return undefined.

Use `className` instead of `class` for `CSS`.

You need to return the `items` array (it will contain all the ui elements). Like this:

```
function shownavlist(allnavitems){
  const items = allnavitems.map( h => {
    return(
        h.links.map( display => {
          return(

            <a href="#" className="dropdown-toggle navbar-link" data-toggle="dropdown">{h.heading}<span className="caret"></span></a>
            <ul className="dropdown-menu {{getTheme slug}}" role="menu">
              <li><a className="navbar-link notAllowed" href="">{display.heading}</a>
              </li>
            </ul>

          )
        })  
     )
  })

  return items;       // <==== added this line

}
```

**Update:**

```
function shownavlist(allnavitems){
  const items = allnavitems.map(h => (
    [

      <a key={1} href="#" className="dropdown-toggle navbar-link" data-toggle="dropdown">
        {h.heading}
        <span className="caret"></span>
      </a>

      <ul key={2} className="dropdown-menu {{getTheme slug}}" role="menu">
        {h.links.map(display => (
          <li key={display.order}>
            <a className="navbar-link notAllowed" href="">{display.heading}</a>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>

    ]
  ))

  return items;

}
```

Added the keys also.

Comment: I want to display them as a dropdown menu but I am not getting it as expected

Comment: I think I am not mapping the JSON data correctly. I am not getting navigation bar with dropdown list instead I am getting the whole list of navigation items

Comment: I want to display heading which will have dropdown items i.e links.heading if possible can you edit the answer with modified mapping.

Comment: i did, try the code in update section. i think that will create a dropdown will all the items.

Comment: Check screenshot -> https://imgur.com/a/9tWjfYT It is not getting displayed as dropdown item list. In that you can see heading is statistics and it has dropdown batting , bowling, stats

Comment: instead of using class (for css class) use className.

Comment: Now I am not able to see dropdown menu when I click on it see this -> https://imgur.com/a/UCLc8n2

Comment: I am referring this html template for dropdown menu in navbar -> https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp

Comment: which version of react you are using?

Comment: Old version of react

Comment: ClubID is same for all objects

Comment: If I remove the keys then I am not getting the list horizontally but it is displaying it vertically possibly due to <div> tag

Comment: check the updated answer, remove the div and use array.

Comment: The previous answer was good i.e without keys but the only problem with that was when I Click on it does not display dropdown menu

Comment: How can I see the previous answers ?

Comment: click on the "edited 4mins back" below the answer, you will be able to see all the edits done previously.

Comment: Check the screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/nZjb433 I am not able to see dropdown when I click on it. That code works fine but on clicking it does not show dropdown menu